SPSS ANOVA and ANCOVA Partial Eta Squared values
I am testing the effectiveness of a group psychotherapy intervention on multiple DVs (assessed via self-report questionnaires). The study design utilizes one intervention and one waitlist control group (n=25 for both) with one pre-test and one post-test of the DVs.
I have analyzed the data in SPSS 27 using both 2-way RM ANOVA (General Linear Model -> Repeated Measures) and univariate ANCOVA (with post-test scores as the DV, the groups as the fixed factor, and pre-test scores as the covariate) and the resulting partial eta squared values are up to 0.7 for some of the DVs. I've found little info on how to interpret partial eta squared values, but they mostly indicate much lower values (0.14) as large effect sizes.
Do these partial eta squared values make sense? And are partial eta squared values a proper way of showcasing effect sizes in such studies or are there more suitable measures?
